# Creating a temp table by using xml.nodes function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the xml structure below. I am trying to create a temp table by using return result but I couldnt do it.

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '
<Root>
  <ValueHolder>
     <Value>3.00</Value>
     <IsNoteDirty>false</IsNoteDirty>
     <Timestamp>
        <StampType>Month</StampType>
        <Stamp>3</Stamp>
        <Year>2007</Year>
     </Timestamp>
     </ValueHolder>
  <ValueHolder>
     <Value>23.00</Value>
     <IsNoteDirty>false</IsNoteDirty>
     <Timestamp>
        <StampType>Month</StampType>
        <Stamp>3</Stamp>
        <Year>2007</Year>
     </Timestamp>
     </ValueHolder>
</Root>'


select Tab.Col.value('(Value)[1]','MONEY') 
          from @xml.nodes('/Root/ValueHolder') Tab(Col)
```

This code works perfect. What I am trying to do is, putting this result to a temp table. I tried this one but it doesnt work

```
select * into #TempTable
    from (select Tab.Col.value('(Value)[1]','MONEY') 
          from @xml.nodes('/Root/ValueHolder') Tab(Col))
```

The error message is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You need table alias for your derived table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
select MoneyValue = Tab.Col.value('(Value)[1]', 'MONEY') 
into #TempTable
from @xml.nodes('/Root/ValueHolder') Tab(Col)
```

Works just fine if I do it this way.